# Give an example of a function having infinite number of point of discontinuities but integrable. Justify.

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

Give an example of a function of one variable having infinite number of point of discontinuities but integrable. Justify.

Please help me.

Comment: Riemann-integrable or Lesbesgue-integrable ?

Comment: Riemann integrable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classical example is [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). It is discontinuous at every rational. On the other hand, if $P$ is a partition of $[0,1]$, then $L(f,P)=0$. It's not hard to prove that$$\inf\left\{U(f,P)\,\middle|\,P\text{ partition of }[0,1]\right\}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$I_n = \left[\frac 1n, \frac{1}{n+1}\right]$$ and $$ f = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n \ \bf 1_{I_n}$$ then $f$ is integrable since the alternatic harmonic series converges.